# Как уменьшить размер файла ibtmp1 в mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql

После обновления с mysql 5.6 до 5.7 появился и несмотря на  innodb_max_undo_log_size       = 50M в конфиге через несколько часов занимает все свободное место на сервере. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: В ibtmp1 лежат временные таблицы, а не журнал транзакций. Судя по всему его максимальный размер ограничить нельзя. Надо смотреть откуда в системе столько временных таблиц и данных в них

Comment: в 5.6 такого не было, но он был значительно медленнее.

Comment: По умолчанию переменная innodb_temp_data_file_path = ibtmp1:12M:autoextend такая. Убрал :autoextend ibtmp1 перестал увеличиваться.

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментариев*

В файле `ibtmp1` лежат временные таблицы, а не журнал транзакций. Надо смотреть откуда в системе столько временных таблиц и данных в них.

По умолчанию директива `innodb_temp_data_file_path` принимает следующее значение

```
innodb_temp_data_file_path = ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
```

Убрал `:autoextend` и файл `ibtmp1` перестал увеличиваться.

Comment: На Ubuntu эту настройку можно добавить в конфигурации mysql
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Answer (score 0):

Всё там можно ограничить.

```
 innodb_temp_data_file_path = ibtmp1:12M:autoextend:max:5G
```

Файл будет ограничен 5 ГБ